# Escaping special characters in Apache SOLR search

Tags: search

[image: Apache solr search landing page]

In Drupal 7 ,

On typing **asdas;'** in search box and searching,**i get blank page**.I have 
integrated Apache solr search in drupal 7.

**SOLR VERSION:** solr-4.7.2
**Drupal Module Used:** apachesolr (https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr)

I don't know how to escape such special characters.

**;** means end of solr query.i think that is causing such issue.  ‪

Site is indexed.And after integrating solr search you get two options when you search a keyword:(see attached image)

1. site(this is solr search option)
2. content(default drupal nodesearch).

For now i have disabled default drupal search i.e node search.

I am using only solr.And now on searching  asdas'; i get a blank page.

**Keynote**: only keyword asds;' i.e Key word having semicolon gives blank page else search works properly.

Attached is example image. Content tab is default drupal search and site tab comes after you integrate apache solr. In my case only site comes as i have disable content search.